# getting offset().top of angular bootstrap tab contents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a two tabs set up like so

```
<tabset>
    <tabA>
        <tab-heading>
        </tab-heading>
        <div resize>
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tabB>
        <tab-heading>
        </tab-heading>
        <div resize>
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

and a directive called resize that finds the browser window height and the distance from the top of the window of the element it is on and then sets the max height of the element to the difference of these two measurements.  it looks like this

```
.directive('resize', function ($window) {
            return {
                restrict: "AE",
                transclude: true,
                scope: true,
                template: '<div id="scroll-container" ng-style="style()" ng-transclude></div>',
                link: function (scope, element) {

                    var w = angular.element($window);
                    scope.getWindowDimensions = function() {
                        return { 'h': w.height() };
                    };

                    scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                        var e = angular.element(element);

                        scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
                        scope.elementOffset = e.offset().top;
                        console.log(scope.windowHeight, scope.elementOffset);

                        scope.style = function() {
                            return {
                                'height': (scope.windowHeight - scope.elementOffset) + "px",
                                'max-height': (scope.windowHeight - scope.elementOffset) + "px",
                                'position': "relative",
                                'overflow': "auto"
                            }
                        }
                    }, true);
                    w.bind('resize', function() {
                        scope.$apply();
                    });
                }
            };
        })
```

this directive works great on tabA but it dosn't seem to be able to get the offset().top of tabB on page load (it logs correctly for tabA but 0 for tabB)

If I swap the tabs around it works for tabB and not tabA

Is there a way to get this to work?

edit1; if I resize the window when tabB is selected the $watch in the directive gets triggered and tab B content gets sized as intended but if I resize the window when tab B is not selected then its the same problem

Comment: It seems like that is because the height of the "hidden" tab **is** 0 because it is _hidden_. Maybe what you can do is also run your resize logic when the tab is switched from hidden to shown.

Comment: Thanks Jose yes this is what I figured after more investigation.  I can do this with the selected="" attribute of the tab directive but I can't figure out how to expose a function in my resize directive that that can call without breaking the current functionality

Comment: Why don't you re-size the container for the tabs? That way you only have to re-size one element and it will always be shown no matter what tab is selected.

Comment: thank-you I am trying that now but how do I force the content of the tabs to scroll if they overflow their parent?

Comment: You can use css: `overflow-y: auto`

Comment: that only works if I set the max-height of the divs to a pixel value, 100% dosn't work, no height setting dosnt work

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution, because I have the same problem now?